# Devx encoding & amp; as & ampx;

Tags: javascript, html

Using a Devx combo box with HTML encoding set to true.  This changes the data in the drop down so that & amp; encodes to & ampx;  which causes a callback error. Devx is definitely making the change in it's javascript. Can't find anything about & ampx; on google which leads me to believe this is a Devx problem.  Has anyone ever encountered this problem?  Any suggestions for a solution?  Turning off encoding for the control stops the problem from happening but we need to have encoding on for other reasons.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Using a devx control, a combo box.  The options data contains an entry with & amp; (note this is an html encoded &).  However, devx is encoding the data as & ampx; (note this encoding character doesn't exist).  this is causing a crash in a postback (because & ampx cannot be decoded).  Devx is definitely doing the encoding of & amp; to & ampx;  I need Devx not to do this or at the very least understand why it is using this bastardised encoding.  I can't find anything about it on Google, so I'm wondering if some one had the same problem and if so how they worked around it.